# simple process bar with asytask

Tags: android, process, android-asynctask

I want to add a simple process bar to my code with asy task. I tryed some exampels but cant see that process bar working. 
I post here my code hope you can help me.
I want to stop process bar when some of my code is done like with some flag to stop the proses bar. 
plese post some code.

thanks a lot!

here my code:

```
private class loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    Context context;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final long waitTime = 1 * 4000L;
    long preTime;
    int progress;

    public loading(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, first.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
  return;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    preTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    synchronized protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        int waited = 0;
        while (waited < 3000) {
            try {


                //   SystemClock.sleep(100); 
                this.wait(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            waited += 100;
        }
        return null;



    }
}
```

Comment: [See this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doInBackground` method needs to call [publishProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) in order for you to update the UI.

After the line `waited += 100;` add:

```
int progress = Math.round((float)waited / 3000 * 100);
publishProgress(progress);
```

Also, the signature of `AsyncTask` is wrong if you intend on using an integer to reflect your progress. The generic parameters are `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`, so in your case, you're not accepting any arguments, or returning any meaningful value from `doInBackground`, but, you *do* want to return an `Integer` to indicate progress.  So, change your class declaration to match:

```
private class loading extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
{
    //your implementation
}
```

Comment: added this line(publishProgress(waited / 3000);) but have error on this line method publishProgress in class android.os.AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Void[]
  found: int
  reason: argument type int does not conform to vararg element type java.lang.Void
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: See my edited answer. Changing the generics used with `AsyncTask` will take care of that.

Comment: ok now I dont have any errors but still my code isnt updating the processbar   synchronized protected Integer doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            int waited = 0;
            while (waited < 3000) {
                try {
                    this.wait(100);
              publishProgress(waited / 3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                waited += 100;
            }
            return null;

        }

Comment: Silly mistake on my part, the division always worked out to be 0, so nothing changed. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling [AsyncTask.publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) and that is why your `onProgressUpdate` method is never called.

And by the way, your class name `loading` brokes naming conventions, that's not a good practice.